Bayes' rule for conditional expectations vs Bayes' rule for probability
I do know that there is two Bayes formulas, one for conditional expectations that is :
$$ \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P} (X\mid \mathcal G) =  \frac{\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q} (X L\mid \mathcal G)}{\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q} (L\mid \mathcal G)} $$
Where $L$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative.
And there is a seconde Bayes formula for conditional probability that is :
$$ \mathbb{P}(A\mid B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}\times \mathbb{P}(B\mid A) $$
My question is : Is there relationship between both formulas? is one a generation of the second one?
I know that Bayes formula for conditional probability came from the fact that :
$$ \mathbb{P}(A\mid B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} $$
Which could be seen as :
$$ \mathbb{E}(\chi_A\mid B) = \frac{\mathbb{E}(\chi_A \times \chi_B)}{\mathbb{E}(\chi_B)} $$
Where $\chi_A$ stand for indicator function.
There is some similarity that make me think there is a relationship between both.
